# Why are the two senses of alpha in hypothesis testing identical?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

My stat book contains a section on hypothesis testing. At the beginning of this section, level of significance is defined as the maximum allowable probability of rejecting the null hypothesis when it is true; level of significance is denoted by alpha.

In the next section the test is described: compute the value of p, “the probability of obtaining a sample statistic with a value as extreme or more extreme than the one determined from the sample data.” If p is less than alpha, we reject the null hypothesis.

I feel I’m missing something here. In the first place we defined alpha as the maximum allowable probability of rejecting a true null; and then we used it as a sort of threshold of plausibility. Why are these two ideas interchangeable? They seem different to me.

Comment: Something in the wording "maximal allowable probability of rejecting the null hypothesis" is misleading to me. I suspect something has been lost in the translation. What is at issue is not the "probability of rejecting the null hypothesis". Instead, attempting to stick with the flavor of the phrase but correct the misleading wording, one might say "maximal allowable probability [of some as yet unspecified event] which would lead one to reject the null hypothesis".

Answer (score 0):

Take a one-sample t test for example. You have a random sample 
$X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ of size $n=20$ from
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma),$ where $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are both unknown.
Suppose we test $H_0: \mu = \mu_0$ against $H_a: \mu > \mu_0$ at the 5% level
of significance, so that $\alpha = .05.$

The sample mean $\bar X$ estimates the population mean $\mu,$ and the sample
standard deviation $S$ estimates the population SD $\sigma.$ The observed
value of the t statistic is

$$t_{obs} = \frac{\bar X - \mu_0}{S/\sqrt{n}}.$$

'Under $H_0$' (statistical language for 'assuming the null hypothesis to be
true'), $t_{obs}$ is a particular observation from $\mathsf{T}(\nu=19)$ Student's t distribution with $\nu = n-1 = 20-1 = 19$
degrees of freedom.

We reject $H_0$ at level $\alpha = .05$ if $t_{obs} \ge t^* = 1.729.$
This 'critical value' $t^*$ can be found by software or in a table of
Student's t distribution (on row 19). It is chosen to cut 5% of the area
from the upper tail of the density curve of $\mathsf{T}(\nu = 19).$
Then we have
$$P(T \ge t^*\;|\; H_0 \text{ True}) = \alpha = .05,$$
where $T \sim \mathsf{T}(19).$

Now, for the P-value, which I will denote by $p$. It is the probability
under $H_0$ that $T$ would take a value greater than $t_{obs}.$
That is,
$$P(T \ge t_{obs}\;|\; H_0 \text{ True}) = p.$$

P-values are an innovation of the computer age. Ordinarily, is not possible to
find the exact P-value of a t test from printed tables of $\mathsf{T}.$

The sketch below shows the PDF of $\mathsf{T}(19)$. Suppose your value $t_{obs} = 1.87,$ based on the $\bar X$ and $S$ from your sample of $X_i$'s. It is
represented by the vertical blue line. The P-value is the area to the right
of this vertical blue line.

The solid vertical dotted red line is at
$t^* = 1.729,$ the critical value for a test at level $\alpha = .05.$
Because $t_{obs} > t^*$ we reject $H_0$ at the 5% level. From R statistical
software I can find the P-value corresponding to $t_{obs} = 1.87$ to be
about $p = 0.385,$ but you will not find this value in an ordinary t table.

```
1 - pt(1.87, 19)  # 'pt' is the CDF of T
## 0.03848638     # P-value corresponding to 't-obs' = 1.87
```

Because the P-value is smaller than .05, I can tell from the P-value that
I should reject $H_0$ at the 5% level.

[image]

The vertical dotted orange line
is at the critical value (2.539) for a test at the 1% level, which you can
find in a printed t table. Because the P-value
is larger than .01, I cannot reject $H_0$ at the 1% level.

If my t table shows only critical values for tests at levels 5% and 1%,
I can see from the t table that the P-value must be bracketed by
.05 and .01, but need software to tell that the P-value is .0385.